# Where to put a "common" controller (for admin/front catalogs) in MVC pattern

Tags: php, symfony

In Symfony 3 I created two subfolders in the "Controller" folder: "admin" and "front", the first one will be responsible for administrative tasks, and the second one for, well, displaying a frontpage.

I have a "UserController", which sits in the "front" folder, simply because there are methods like "register" or "login" which obviously cannot be in "admin" folder (because one must be logged in to access this url)

Now I want to create a possibility to edit user details in the admin panel. That method would be called "edit" for example.

What's the best way to do it? From the architectural pattern point of view?

1. Create another UserController in "admin" folder.
2. Move existing UserController into a new folder, called e.g. "common", and add the "edit" method there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the 2 options you have specified i would go with the 1st option. It's a good idea to seperate controllers as well by functionality. (Eg. modifying tasks, etc).

But as I understand you actually have 3 roles all together. (Admin, Member and Anonymous). So you might also think about grouping the categories as followed:

admin, public, member

Keeping the common member controllers and tasks in there, login and register in public and full admin task in that folder. Admins usually for example can edit data for members as well. But member can only edit his/her own data.

Comment: OK, thank you! Actually I've been having this dilemma since I remember :)

Comment: No problem! Just remember you are already following a good practice and at this point just go with what seems to be the fastest and easiest way. Re-use functions whenever possible (eg. no need for member and admin to have seperate function to change their password for example).

Comment: Yes, what I'm going to do is that I'll have ONE UserModel and put common functions there, I hope this is OK.

Comment: Keep the functions in Controller. Models are ment for data handling.

Comment: OK, but I'll have two or three controllers, I don't want to duplicate code, so where to put functions common for all those controllers?

Comment: If it's a member action that an admin can do as well put it under member. But when it's admin only then put it under admin.

So change password functionality would go to member controller. But change password for any other user would go under admin controller as it can only be accessed by admin.